# airflow DAG triggering for time consuming runs

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I am completely new to Airflow and am trying to grasp the concepts of scheduling and default args.

I have a scenario where I would like to schedule my DAG **hourly** to do some data transfer task between a source and a database. What I am trying to understand is, lets say one of my DAG runs has triggered at 00:00 AM. Now if it takes more than an hour for this run to successfully complete all of its tasks (say 1 hour 30 min), does it mean that the next DAG run that was supposed to be triggered at 01:00 AM will NOT get triggered but the DAG run from 02:00 AM will get triggered?

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
In order to avoid, you need catchup=True for the DAG object.

Reference : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html

(Search for Catchup)

Answer (score 0):

Airflow Scheduler used to monitor all DAGs and tasks in Airflow.Default Arguments can be used to create tasks with default parameters in DAG.
The first DAG runs based on start_date and runs based on scheduled_interval sequentially. Scheduler doesn’t trigger tasks until the period has ended.For your requirement you can set [dag.catchup](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#catchup) to true as to run the DAG for each completed interval and scheduler will execute them sequentially.Catchup is used to start the DAG run since the last data interval which has not started for any data interval.